# How to stop drawing in tiles using the drawGraphicsData method?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

In the following example I am drawing in a canvas using a bitmap for the line stroke. When I release the mouse button, I query **drawHolder** for it's graphical content and save the results in the variable **results** for later use, using **readGraphicsData**.

When I press the green button, I submit the **results** vector to **copyHolder** to render the shape, using **drawGraphicsData** method.

This is where things get interesting: if you have a look at *pic2*, **copyHolder** contains additional graphical content outside the borders of **copyHolder**. I think the problem is with **drawGraphicsData**, since I had a look over the contents of **results** vector and it seems that it contains some extra **GraphicsPath** instances.

Can you think of a solution how to delete/hide these exta paths **WITHOUT** using a mask ?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

```
var result:Vector.<IGraphicsData > ;

loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,loadData);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new (getDefinitionByName(String("myBitmapData"))) as BitmapData;


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent)
{
    drawHolder.graphics.lineStyle(20);
    drawHolder.graphics.lineBitmapStyle(bitmapData, null, false, true);
    drawHolder.graphics.moveTo(mouseX - drawHolder.x, mouseY - drawHolder.u);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
}

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent)
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
    result = drawHolder.graphics.readGraphicsData(false);
}

function onEnterFrame(e:Event)
{
    drawHolder.graphics.lineTo(mouseX - drawHolder.x, mouseY - drawHolder.y);
}


function loadData(e:MouseEvent)
{
    copyHolder.graphics.clear();
    copyHolder.graphics.drawGraphicsData(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your code, it says "drawHolder.u" instead of "drawHolder.y" in `onMouseDown()`. I think this one is in response of extra lines, as you do `moveTo()` to wrong coordinates. And second, there is a reference to extra elements in `readGraphicsData()` result in the manual:

*"although the original vector content is drawn using the drawGraphicsData() method, the vector data objects retrieved by the readGraphicsData() method do not exactly match the ones passed in to the drawGraphicsData() method. For example, the result data includes GraphicsSolidFill and GraphicsEndFill commands, both of which are implied but not actually present in the original graphics data."*

[Source (Adobe manual)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData%28%29)

It's also worth noticing that `readGraphicsData` returns values relative to stage, not the parent `DisplayObject` of the graphics being queried. Consider altering source position and transform prior to copying the graphics contents.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typo. I fixed the typo and positioned the 2 canvases at (0,0), so that the coordinated systems to be synchronized with the stage coordinates. But this also doesn't solve the problem., as you said, the vector contents of drawGraphicsData() method does not match with the ones sent by readGraphicsData(). I think the better solution would be to add a mask, since I don't see other alternative.